# How do I assign different weights to columns in SQL Server Full Text Search?

Tags: sql, full-text-search, ranking

I'm using SQL Server 2008 FTS and I'd like to be able to integrate weighted rankings into my search results.  However, I'd like to weight the columns that a search term is found in differently.  For example, if I have a Title column and a Description column, I want matches fond in Title to rank higher than matches in Description.

Is this possible in SQL Server 2008?  As far as can I see, I can only add weights to specific terms, not column locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FREETEXTTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx) function on each column independently and then assign your weights to the Rank column that is returned. I believe I read somewhere though that the Rank column isn't necessarily valid for comparisons across searches, though, so you may need to experiment to ensure that you get accurate results.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title, filename, sum(relevance)
FROM (
    SELECT title, filename, 10 AS relevance FROM page WHERE title like ‘%about%’
    UNION
    SELECT title, filename, 7 AS relevance FROM page WHERE filename like ‘%about%’
    UNION
    SELECT title, filename, 5 AS relevance FROM page WHERE keywords like ‘%about%’
    UNION
    SELECT title, filename, 2 AS relevance FROM page WHERE description like ‘%about%’
) results
GROUP BY title, filename
ORDER BY relevance desc;
```